Eclipse gave me an error saying it couldn't find the file.. How can I resolve it?
18:08:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project LED ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/lib/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/Legacy/stm32f7xx_hal_can.c
Invoking: GNU Arm Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Os -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -g -std=gnu11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/lib/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/Legacy/stm32f7xx_hal_can.d" -MT"src/lib/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/Legacy/stm32f7xx_hal_can.o" -c -o "src/lib/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/Legacy/stm32f7xx_hal_can.o" "../src/lib/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/Legacy/stm32f7xx_hal_can.c"
../src/lib/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/Legacy/stm32f7xx_hal_can.c:114:27: fatal error: stm32f7xx_hal.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/lib/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/Legacy/subdir.mk:20: src/lib/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/Legacy/stm32f7xx_hal_can.o] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

This error occurred. How should I handle it?
STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver This file contains an Inc file and a Src file. The header file related to stm32 is contained in the Inc file, and the .c file is contained in the Src file.

"contained in the Inc file" You probable mean Inc folder, not file. You need to add that folder to the build command line.

It is not Eclipse giving you the error. It is your compiler - in this case GCC. I assume it cannot find the file, because you did not add the include path with the -I option.

This is what Eclipse does: it produces mysterious linker errors - and that's apparently the core purpose of the IDE. It's too dumb to realize that a file which you have added to the workspace needs to be linked from the path where that file is stored. You have to tell it to do so explicitly.

@UniversE Every other IDE but Eclipse adds source files to the build automatically when they are added to the project. That is what IDEs are for, it's not a problem caused by the compiler at all. If you have to manually tweak the build path for every single sub folder, you might as well be writing a make file manually as if it's still the 1990s.

@Lundin Maybe not the best place to discuss this. But what you are expecting is for simple Hello World. Have you seen all the compiler options in the output above? How in the world should the IDE determine them automagically. For every reasonable project you do have to specify build options on your own, no matter what. Adding random include paths without being asked is also something I would not want from my IDE. It could be, e.g., that I want different include paths for different builds, in particular when cross compiling for different platforms. Usually that's what configure is for.

@UniversE Compiler settings is a separate matter really, IDEs have a place where you can enter all that. But no other IDE using gcc-like compilers also requires you to enter a bunch of -I options manually on top of that, only Eclipse. And there's no reason why you would want different paths for different builds - you'd rather want different files. (All of which is better handled by version control than by the IDE itself.)

@Lundin I would be the last person on earth to defend Eclipse^^ But in fact it is not so unusual that you need to configure a "special" directory layout (e.g. in this case a separte Inc folder as sibling to the Src folder) at least somewhere in your IDE. Either by providing the specific option or by entering it in some textfield somewhere in your project settings. Or sometimes even as simple as rightclick on that folder and say "add to source path" or "add to include" path. Anyway, I just wanted to point out, where the error message is actually coming from. That's all :)
